# Heteroskedacity and non-normality - What to do?

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

I conducted an experiment in which I am trying to model the relationship between my response weed_coverage [%] and the predictors soil moisture [%] + treatment + distance. Weed_coverage and soil_moisture are continuous, treatment and distance are categorical with 2 levels each. I measured soil moisture on 5 dates, at 7 kettleholes each date and at 8 subplots per each kettlehole, with 4 measurements per each subplot.
I checked diagnostic plots for the model

```
mod_1 <- lm(weed_coverage~ soil_moisture* distance, data = Unkraut)
```

and to me it looks like I am dealing with non-normality and heteroskedacity of residual errors of Y. Also I have non-independent observations. As far as I see it I have these options:

1. Transform Y to get rid of non-normality + use robust standard errors with the sandwich package and apply a linear mixed model
2. Use a better fitting distribution for Y , e.g Beta and apply a generalized linear mixed model (with a beta response)

I did a GLMM with a beta response, but to me the results are very unintuitive to interprete, because you get log-odds or whatever and I dont really understand those.
I heard that transforming Y is not optimal either. Below are the diagnostic plots
So what do you think? What is the best option in my case? I am new to statistics, so I am looking for the "simplest" approach that still delivers adequate reliable results and is easy to interprete and understand. Thanks a lot for your help
[image]

Comment: Use `coeftest()` from the `lmtest` library to use robust standard errors and you're on your way. Not a technical answer but its what most people do.

Comment: Thank you! But what to do about the non-normality? Whats the best way in my situation to deal with it? I want to avoid transformation if thats somehow possible, because I heard its not so good..

Comment: Normality is a pretty restrictive condition, you want to make sure your estimates are unbiased and if there is heteroskedasticity just use robust standard errors. Even with non normality your results are a go.

Comment: Thank you EcoJohn! Below Demetri wrote that he thinks a beta regression would be more appropriate. Now I am confused. Is non-normality really just a "minor" issue that can be more or less neglected? Because I think I read that its not that important.. What do you think?

Comment: I dont know anything about beta regression, but I see no issue using OLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I anticipate that the behaviour shown in the qqplot and residual plot is because of floor/ceiling effects.  If weed coverage is measured as a percent then a linear model is not really the most appropriate model because it is not constrained to be within the unit interval.  That doesn't stop people from using linear models for percent data (indeed there are times when it performs just as well), but in circumstances when the outcome is near the boundary the model can perform quite poorly.

I would suggest using a Beta regression instead of a linear regression.  This model should be able to accommodate the boundary.

Comment: Thanks. I read that bootstrapping could also be and option to deal with non-normality of residuals of Y. What do you think about that? I would like to avoid a glmm with beta response since I dont really understand the results of the regression..

Comment: @Effigy Bootstrapping does not automatically fix all model deficiencies.  If you're interested in the best linear approximation, then by all means bootstrap a linear regression.  The core question is really "are you interested in the best linear approximation" or do you think you can do a little better by accommodating the limitations of the data generating process (i.e. the floor and ceiling effects).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I dont want to do a a linear approximation by all costs, but it seems that transformation isnt recommend either and a GLMM with beta response is hard to interprete for me. So I am wondering if the trade-off in terms of accuracy of the model vs. interpretatability if I chose bootstrapping vs glmm + beta or anything else is worth it if you know what I mean..

Comment: @Effigy If you choose to do bootstrapping with the linear model, the inferences you make will be about the best linear approximation.  If you don't want that, don't bootstrap.  A beta regression is harder to interpret, but if you want the most realistic fit to the data, you're going to have to learn a little more statistics.  Unfortunately, nothing comes for free.